# [java][Calendar] - Filter my records from a Arraylist<Bean> Weekely

Tags: java, arrays, jakarta-ee, calendar

i'm new in java programming, and i need help to filter my records from an array list weekly(first day of every week [Monday]) in the current year.

i have showed all my records from an ArrayList in a simple table result:

```
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
| ID | Name | LastName   | Email | Registration Date |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
| 1  | Name1 | LastName1 | Email | 01-01-2017        |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
| 2  | Name2 | LastName2 | Email | 05-02-2017        |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
| 3  | Name3 | LastName3 | Email | 15-02-2017        |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
| 4  | Name4 | LastName4 | Email | 18-03-2017        |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
| 5  | Name5 | LastName5 | Email | 22-04-2017        |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
| 6  | Name6 | LastName6 | Email | 15-05-2017        |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
| 7  | Name7 | LastName7 | Email | 26-06-2017        |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
| 8  | Name8 | LastName8 | Email | 26-06-2017        |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
```

this the result i need to show using Registration date like a filter to filter all my records weekly:

```
+--------------------+
|Week from 02-01-2017|
+----+-------+-------+---+-------+-------------------+
| ID | Name | LastName   | Email | Registration Date |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
| 1  | Name1 | LastName1 | Email | 02-01-2017        |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
| 2  | Name2 | LastName2 | Email | 05-01-2017        |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+

+--------------------+
|Week from 13-02-2017|
+----+-------+-------+---+-------+-------------------+
| ID | Name | LastName   | Email | Registration Date |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
| 3  | Name3 | LastName3 | Email | 15-02-2017        |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+

+--------------------+
|Week from 13-03-2017|
+----+-------+-------+---+-------+-------------------+
| 4  | Name4 | LastName4 | Email | 18-03-2017        |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+

+--------------------+
|Week from 17-03-2017|
+----+-------+-------+---+-------+-------------------+
| 5  | Name5 | LastName5 | Email | 22-04-2017        |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+

+--------------------+
|Week from 15-05-2017|
+----+-------+-------+---+-------+-------------------+
| 6  | Name6 | LastName6 | Email | 15-05-2017        |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
| 7  | Name6 | LastName6 | Email | 19-05-2017        |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+

+--------------------+
|Week from 26-06-2017|
+----+-------+-------+---+-------+-------------------+
| 8  | Name7 | LastName7 | Email | 26-06-2017        |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
| 9  | Name8 | LastName8 | Email | 29-06-2017        |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
```

The date in "week from dd-MM-yyyy" mean all Mondays in the current year when my program is executed can be executed in 2026 and filter the records weekly.

this is the code i developed:

```
//from an Arraylist instantiated:
List<CertificatMajCrBean> lines = new ArrayList<CertificatMajCrBean>();
```

with the elements i want to add:

```
lines.add(records);
```

//i show the result like that:

```
System.out.println("+---------+----------------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+");
System.out.println("| ID      | Name         | LastName        | Email            | Registration Date        |");
System.out.println("+---------+----------------+---------------------+------------------+-------------------+");
for (CertificatMajCrBean line: lignes){

System.out.println("| "+numRec+"  | "+line.getName()+"  | "+line.getLastName()+"   | "+line.getEmail() +"  | "+line.getRegistrationDate()+" |");
System.out.println("+---------+----------------+---------------------+------------------+---------------------------+");
numRec  ++;

}
```

into this iteration i want to add my filter.

Any help to make this algorithm real, many thanks !

Comment: Your question makes a lot of sense. You should show us your effort or at least tell us how your search and research fell short of solving your task. This will give us a much better starting point for guiding you on.

Comment: Your tags disturb me a bit, at least one of them. As a new Java programmer you shouldn’t be learning about nor using `SimpleDateFormat`. It’s long outdated. Represent your dates as `LocalDate`. If you need formatting or parsing, use `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: Several date values (e.g. `19-05-2017`) in expected output does not exist in the input. Please edit it to avoid confusion. Next, in the first expected output, `02-01-2017` and `05-02-2017` do not belong to same week.

Comment: With a `LocalDate` use `registrationDate.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY))` to find the Monday where the week of the registration date begins (provided that your week begins on Monday, but I take it that it does).

Comment: `29-02-2017`? :-)

Comment: Hi again this suggestion its for Java 8, for the moment i'm using only Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that in the name of good style and of breaking a problem into smaller pieces first we separate the *computation* of your result from the *printing* of it. To that end we need a data structure that can hold a number of lists of beans, one list per week. I suggest:

```
    Map<LocalDate, List<CertificatMajCrBean>> byWeek = new TreeMap<>();
```

Most often one would use a `HashMap` rather than a `TreeMap`. You may, but the advantage of a `TreeMap` is that it will keep the map sorted by date, which will help us when we want to print the weekly lists in chronological order.

For the computation, iterate through your `ArrayList` the way you are probably already doing. For each `CertificatMajCrBean` from the list, get the registration date. I am assuming this is a `LocalDate` as I suggested in a comment. Find the Monday where the week begins from `bean.getRegistrationDate().with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY))`. I know it looks complicated, but it’s lovely terse. As the method name suggests, it finds the previous Monday of the registration date or the same date if it is already a Monday. Next, check if this Monday is already a key in the map. It’s easiest to use `byWeek.get(mondayOfRegWeek)`. This will return `null` the first time because there isn’t already a map entry. In this case, create a new `ArrayList`, store your bean into it and put in into the map: `byWeek.put(mondayOfRegWeek, weeklyBeans);` where `weeklyBeans` is your newly created list. If `byWeek.get(mondayOfRegWeek)` returned a list, just add the bean to it and you’re done. After you’ve processed all your beans from your list, your map is finished.

For printing the result use a `for` loop over the entry set of the map:

```
    for (Map.Entry<LocalDate, List<CertificatMajCrBean>> entry : byWeek.entrySet()) {
        // print beans from one week here
    }
```

Inside the `for` loop use `entry.getKey()` to get the Monday where the week begins. If you just print the date, it will come out as `2017-06-26`. To format it in some other way, you may use a `DateTimeFormatter`. To get the list of beans for the week, use `entry.getValue()`. Again you may use a loop inside the loop to print each bean.

If some of it calls for clarification, you may want to check [the API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) first, or else revert in a comment here.

If you had been advanced, I would have told you to use a `Stream` and `Collectors.groupingBy()` for the computation. If you are new to programming you probably don’t want to try that just yet.

Comment: Many thanks i edited the main body of my question to add how i print my records from my ArrayList<CertificatMajCrBean>, will try to develop your suggestion seams complicated but will do !

Comment: The thing is i'm using java 7, can't import LocaleDate, what i should do ? @Ole V.V.

Comment: i have only Locale in  java.util

Comment: The easy and futureproof answer is upgrade to Java 8. If you cannot do that, get the modern Java date and Time classes in [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). I shall be happy to edit my answer and include more information when I get time.

Comment: thank you a lot, i cant update to java 8 all my project is in java 7 and have to be in java 7, i want to implement a solution with java 7 without using external dependancies.

Comment: Poor you. :-) `java.util.Calendar` offers support for what you require, but I hate telling so since it is long outdated. These days there are so many better alternatives, JodaTime, Java 8, ThreeTen Backport, Time4J, … Everyone of these offers a simpler solution than `Calendar` does. I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: you having so much experience, JodaTime dependency can solve my issue do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: If you are happy with Joda-Time I would consider it a better and simpler option than bare Java 7. Joda-Time is in maintenance mode, though, and the folks behind it were the main driving forces in designing the newer Java date and time API. So if chosing an external dependency for my Java 7 project, I personally would prefer ThreeTen Backport over Joda-Time.

Comment: Ok i will add ThreeTen Backport in my dependencies to use LocalDate, hope i can solve this issue !